# Embedded child component doesn't get changed when I click a new one with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I started to use React Router earlier today for the first time, and I would like to embed an article's view inside the article's index. This works, the only problem is that when I want to change articles, the url changes, I get informations from the new one too, but nothing changes visually.

Here is my code from both the parent component and the child component:

**articles.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import utils from '../lib/functionsLibrary';
import Article from './article';
import {Link, Route} from "react-router-dom";

export default class Articles extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {articles: null};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;
        utils.loader(window.location.origin + '/all_articles.json', function (articles) {
            self.setState({articles: articles})
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {articles} = this.state;
        const { match, settings } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {
                        articles !== null &&
                        articles.map(function (a, i) {
                            return (
                                <li key={i}>
                                    <Link to={`/articles/${a.slug}`}>{a.title}</Link>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
                <Route path={`/articles/:slug`} component={Article} settings={settings}/>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path={match.url}
                    render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
                />
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

**article.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import utils from '../lib/functionsLibrary';

export default class Article extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {article: null};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;
        // I retrieve the list of articles ever saved, and filter them
        // with the slug I passed as parameter / url
        utils.loader(window.location.origin + '/all_articles.json', function (articles) {
            self.setState({
                article: articles.find(a => a.slug === self.props.match.params.slug)
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        // returns the correct data
        console.log(this.props.match.params.slug);
        const { article } = this.state;

        return (
            article !== null &&
            <div>
                <h1>{article.title}</h1>
                <p>Tags: {article.tags}</p>
                <p>{article.content}</p>
                <img src={article.image.url} alt=""/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Did I forgot about something?

Thank you in advance

Comment: errors in the browser console?

Comment: Absolutely none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Article` component is not remounting when url params are changed, so `componentDidMount` method is not called. You should use `componentWillReceiveProps` method to check if params are changed.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadArticle(this.props.match.params.slug);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.slug !== newProps.match.params.slug) {
        this.loadArticle(newProps.match.params.slug);
    }
  }
```

> [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tqvgsn)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I got trouble adapting your code because I forgot to change the `componentDidMount()` function, but now everything works perfectly :D